a float function returning 1.#QUAN0 instead of the actual values
I have written this program to give me the value of i exposed to the power of j using recursion. As I am a student, practicing different methods of solving the same problem might be beneficial for me. The logic behind the code is working fine but when using negative power the function np() returns 1.#QUAN0 instead of the actual value. I do not understand why this is happening.
PS: This code with negative power is working fine in my senior's laptop.
#include <stdio.h>

int pp(int i, int j, int m)
{
    if(j==0)
        return m;
    else
    {
        m *= i;
        pp(i,j-1,m);
    }
}

float np(float i,int j,float m)
{
    if(j==0)
        return m;
    else
    {
        m *= (1/i);
        np(i,j+1,m);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("Enter the value of i=");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Enter the value of j=");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    if(j>=0)
        printf("%d",pp(i,j,1));
    else
        printf("%f",np((float)i,j,(float)1));

    return 0;
}


You have two "legs" of the if-statement in np, but only one return. What happens in the else-part? (Hint: it also needs a return)

np(i,j+1,m); are you sure you want j+1 here? May be your intent was j-1?

@fukanchik this is for case where j<0 so I believe he did intend + here

If you are missing a return statement, then this means that you are attempting to write C code without first having enabled all warnings on your compiler. Do not do that. Do not do anything at all unless you first figure out how to enable all warnings that your compiler can give you.  Programming instructors who do not teach this to students should not be teaching; they should be milking goats.

Why should I always enable compiler warnings?

The problem is that in the pp and np only the branch where j=0 has a return statement.
You should add return in the else branch as well:
for pp:
else{
    m*=i;
    return pp(i,j-1,m);
}

For np:
else{
    m*=(1/i);
    return np(i,j+1,m);
}

